dotnet publish error WASM0005: Unable to resolve WebAssembly runtime pack version
I use dotnet publish to deploy a blazor webassembly hosted app to IIS:
location of server project> dotnet publish -c Release  -r win-x64 --self-contained false --output {AppDir}

But I get this error:
C:\Users\..\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.webassembly.pack\8.0.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WebAssembly.Browser.tar
gets(231,5): error WASM0005: Unable to resolve WebAssembly runtime pack version [C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorHosted\Bl
azorHosted\Client\BlazorHosted.Client.csproj]

How to correct this?
EDIT
Since I get this error on a bigger .Net 8.0 project, I created a test webassembly hosted project with .Net 7.0, But I see inside package manager that webassembly.pack version is 8.0 while I created this project as 7.0, The error is the same:

EDIT2 I updated my visual studio 2022, with a newly created webassembly project, the error now happens for .net 8.0.2:
    C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorHosted3\BlazorHosted3\Server>dotnet publish
        -c Release  -r win-x64 --self-contained false
     MSBuild version 17.9.4+90725d08d for .NET   Determining projects to restore...   
    Restored C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorHosted3\BlazorHosted3\Client\BlazorHosted3.Client.csproj (in 1.66 sec).   
    2 of 3 projects are up-to-date for restore.  
     BlazorHosted3.Shared -> C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorHosted3\BlazorHosted3\Shared\bin\Release\net7.0\BlazorHosted3.Sh ared.dll 
    C:\Users\..\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.webassembly.pack\8.0.2\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WebAssembly.Browser.tar gets(231,5): 
error WASM0005: Unable to resolve WebAssembly runtime pack version [C:\Users\..\Desktop\BlazorHosted3\B lazorHosted3\Client\BlazorHosted3.Client.csproj]

in the mentioned (in error) file:
 <Target Name="_GetWasmRuntimePackVersion">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <_WasmRuntimePackVersion>%(ResolvedRuntimePack.NuGetPackageVersion)</_WasmRuntimePackVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Error Code="WASM0005" Text="Unable to resolve WebAssembly runtime pack version" Condition="'$(_WasmRuntimePackVersion)' == ''" />
 </Target>


did you install the IIS binaries for .net on the server?

If you mean the new .NET Core Hosting Bundle, I didn't install it yet but when I publish from Visual Studio publish works.

I installed .Net core Hosting bundle 8.0.3 but still get error

"I'm aware that WA significantly changed from version 7 to version 8. However, I'm not sure if changing the .NET version in a web assembly project is a viable solution to your problem. I suggest checking out the "What's New in .NET 8" videos, as they introduce a completely new architecture. Instead of trying to update the existing project, it might be better to create a new one and transfer the code over."

Did you try to delete obj, bin and .vs folders ?

yes has no effect

I removed -c Release  -r win-x64 --self-contained false and with this command:
dotnet publish --output {AppDir}

The publish is successful and without error.

Just removing the --self-contained switch was enough for me. It doesn't make sense to use that one for a Blazor app.
